# Text over image without absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put some text over an image in the middle of a page.

I saw an example like this:

```
<img src="image.png" style="z-index: -1;" />
<p style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px;>text</p>
```

but when i try to center it the text will not be in the center.

```
<div>
    <center>
         <img src="image.png" style="z-index: -1;" />
         <p style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px;>text</p>
    </center>
</div>
```

How can i create a text over image without absolute possition?

Comment: Without using absolute and relative positioning, you will need to set the image to be a background of a containing div.

Comment: Or negative margin ben

Comment: @omri is this image decoration or is it crucial for your content?

Comment: Please don't use `<center>`. It has been deprecated a long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the absolute positioning, it's how you center the text. The text in the paragraph will be centered, but that has no effect as the paragraph has the same width as the text. When you make the paragraph absolutely positioned it no longer gets its width from its parent.

You can make the parent the same width as the image, and the paragraph the same width as the parent, and then center the text inside the paragraph. Example:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crp6V/

Note: The `position: relative;` on the parent element makes it the origin for the absolute position of the paragraph.

If you want to center both the image and the text, then you would just make the paragraph the same width as the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/crp6V/2/

Comment: Very impressive sir, you are correct! you may have won this battle, but I will win this war ;]

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is ofcourse set image as paragraph background.

if you know the exact size of the paragraph and if it's defined:

```
p.overlay {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Keep the z-index and such as before, and for example this could work.
An other thing, is because the p will not be centered due to being absolutely positioned, but if the parent is relative and the image has the full width of the parent, you could make the paragraph display as block, 100% width, and then center the text.

```
   p.overlay {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center
    }
```

So absolute position could still work