# How do you make text that has part of image?

Tags: html, css

Was curious how you make image text kind of like this

https://dribbble.com/shots/2150115-Alltracks/attachments/393908

Comment: Make a div with background-image

Comment: Whoops, apologies for my old answer, I misunderstood the question! -CM

Comment: this may help https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ OR https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text over image without absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264276/text-over-image-without-absolute-position)

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to approach this. You could set a background image across the page in CSS3, for example, which would look like this:

```
html {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You may also want to see [Clipping and Masking in CSS](https://css-ricks.com/clipping-masking-css/). (left in comments by [nzkks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495469/nzkks))